# Where did the "Cited by" link go on Google search results?

Tags: google-scholar

For as long as I can remember, Google search results that contained hits to papers in Google scholar were accompanied by a clickable "Cited by xxx" link that led to a list of all the citing works in Google scholar. Recently, this behavior seems to have been disabled. Now instead of a link, all I see is grey text with the citation count:

[image: non-clickable cited by link]

Mundane though it seems, being able to easily pull up all citing papers was a huge time saver, and I find myself sorely missing this feature. Is there a way to re-enable it? Why did Google disable this helpful feature?

Comment: Not sure why, but you still see this clickable link if you search directly in google scholar.

Comment: True, but it's still much more convenient to be able to access this information directly from the main Google search engine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it can be re-enabled (seems unlikely), but a workaround could be to use the Google Scholar button* browser extension ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-scholar-button/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-scholar-button/ldipcbpaocekfooobnbcddclnhejkcpn?hl=en)). You can select the title of the paper, then click the button to see its search results on Google Scholar, including a clickable "Cited by" button. Alternatively, you could directly press the button if the title is already present in your Google search terms. It is not as convenient as having the link directly in the search results, but is still easier than separately opening Google Scholar, in my opinion.

Screenshot for reference:
[image: example]

*<sub>No affiliation</sub>

Comment: Thanks -- unfortunate that it does not work on Safari.